# Animating SVGs Via CSS

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I found this immensely helpful [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/NRwrNp) about animating SVGs via CSS.  First question, would it also work with line elements?  I tried it with a few different keywords but didn't succeed:

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.path path {
  transition: d 400ms;
}
.line line {
  transition: x1 400ms, y1 400ms, x2 400ms, y2 400ms;
}
.path:hover path {
  d: path("M10,90 L90,10");
}
.line:hover line {
  x1: line("10");
  y1: point("90");
  x2: coord("90");
  y1: pos("10");
}
```

```html
<svg class="path" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="5">
    <path d="M10,10 L90,90"/>
  </g>
</svg>
<svg class="line" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="5">
    <line x1="10" y1="10", x2="90" y2="90"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Also, where is the documentation for this, the fact that you have to write `d: path("M10,90 L90,10");` instead of just `d: "M10,90 L90,10";` seems non-trivial to me, how would that work with other properties of other elements?

Comment: Though, for a line, there would be a solution using transforms + `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke` to modify your line as if you did change their attributes, but that'd be a lot more complex than using a simple `path()` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only [presentation attributes](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#PresentationAttributes) have their counter-parts in CSS.

As of today, here is the list of these attributes:

> | Properties with a presentation attribute | Elements that support the presentation attribute |
> | --- | --- |
> | cx, cy | ‘circle’ and ‘ellipse’ |
> | height, width, x, y | ‘foreignObject’, ‘image’, ‘rect’, ‘svg’, ‘symbol’, and ‘use’ |
> | r | ‘circle’ |
> | rx, ry | ‘ellipse’ and ‘rect’ |
> | d | ‘path’ |
> | fill | Any element in the SVG namespace except for animation elements, which have a different ‘fill’ attribute. |
> | transform | For historical reasons, the transform property gets represented by different presentation attributes depending on the SVG element it applies to: - transform Any element in the SVG namespace with the exception of the ‘pattern’, ‘linearGradient’ and ‘radialGradient’ elements. - ‘patternTransform’ ‘pattern’. ‘patternTransform’ gets mapped to the transform CSS property[css-transforms-1]. - ‘gradientTransform’ ‘linearGradient’ and ‘radialGradient’ elements. ‘gradientTransform’ gets mapped to the transform CSS property [css-transforms-1]. |
> | alignment-baseline, baseline-shift, clip-path, clip-rule, color, color-interpolation, color-interpolation-filters, cursor, direction, display, dominant-baseline, fill-opacity, fill-rule, filter, flood-color, flood-opacity, font-family, font-size, font-size-adjust, font-stretch, font-style, font-variant, font-weight, glyph-orientation-horizontal, glyph-orientation-vertical, image-rendering, letter-spacing, lighting-color, marker-end, marker-mid, marker-start, mask, mask-type, opacity, overflow, paint-order, pointer-events, shape-rendering, stop-color, stop-opacity, stroke, stroke-dasharray, stroke-dashoffset, stroke-linecap, stroke-linejoin, stroke-miterlimit, stroke-opacity, stroke-width, text-anchor, text-decoration, text-overflow, text-rendering, transform-origin, unicode-bidi, vector-effect, visibility, white-space, word-spacing, writing-mode | Any element in the SVG namespace. |

You can see that lines's `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2` aren't there, and thus can't be controlled and thus animated by CSS.

For the values `d` can receive in CSS it's [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d) and basically it can receive either a [`path()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/path) function, or the value `none`.

Comment: Great, thanks so much!  So, if I want to control those values from JS, I'd also use the style attribute and not `setAttribute`, right?

Comment: Which values? For the ones that are not presentational, you don't have the choice, it's through the attribute (either `setAttribute`, or the IDL animatedLength `elem.x1.baseVal.value`). For the presentational ones, you can indeed use CSS, or you can keep the attributes if you prefer, though CSS has higher precedence over the attributes.

Comment: I mean the presentational ones.  I tried it with `setAttribute` and didn't get the animation (transition), so in order to have that, my impression was that I have to always use the style property?

Comment: Yes, to have the transition works properly in every browser it's best to use only CSS. Per specs updating the attributes should also work the same, but it's true that not all browsers do this correctly (looking at you Safari).